# Validate multiple belongs_to relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say we have the following data structure (imagine as a loop).

```
MyModel * -- 1 User 1 -- * Clients 0 -- * MyModel
```

Thus, the MyModel looks like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :user_id, :client_id, # ...

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
```

So it *can* belong to a client but *must* belong to a user. Also a client *must* belong to a user.

But how can I assert, that *if* someone saves a `MyModel` instance belonging to a client, that the client actually belongs to the user? Do I have to write a custom validator for this or is there any validation shortcut I overlooked?

**Solution:**

Following p.matsinopoulos' answer, I now did the following. I don't assign the foreign keys to `MyModel` before saving but rather the objects directly.

```
  # my_model_controller.rb

  def create
    m = MyModel.create(whitelist_parameters(params[:my_model]))
    m.user = current_user

    if(params[:my_model][:client_id].present?)          
      client = Client.find params[:my_model][:client_id]
    end

    # ...
  end
```

This way I can at first validate if there is a `Client` with such an ID at all. Then I implemented the custom validator by p.matsinopoulos. It's not tested yet, but since I am now working with the objects, it should do the trick.

Comment: If MyModel belongs to client, and the client must belong to a user, then do you require a `belongs_to :user` in MyModel? I would have perhaps `has_one :user, :through => :client` and validate the client/user dependency in the Client model.

Comment: Yes, client also `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :my_models`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would have written a custom validator.

```
validate :client_belongs_to_user

protected

def client_belongs_to_user
  errors[:client] << 'must own the user' if client.present? && client.user != user
end
```

Comment: Thank you! But since I'm doing everything with the IDs, I'd write `client.user_id != user_id`(or is it `:user_id` then?)

Comment: Somehow, this does not work. Strange thing is, I can even put in a `client_id` that does not even exist. Isn't Rails supposed to check if the `belongs_to` relation is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, building on what you have:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_one :user, :through => :client

  attribute_accessor :client_id

  validates :client_id, :presence => true
  ...
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :my_models
  belongs_to :user

  attribute_accessor :user_id

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, a `MyModel` can belong to a user without having a client assigned. So the reference to the user is always there, but not the client reference.

Comment: Thank you for making that clarification.